# calculating absolute value

Tags: apex

In the data constructor, I have following statement:

```
        this.data1 = Reve/1000;
```

This statement is working fine.

Now I want to calculate the absolute value so I rewrite this statement as:

```
        this.data1 = ABS(Reve/1000);
```

and it gives an error: **Method does not exist or incorrect signature: ABS(Decimal)**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try:

```
 this.data1 = math.abs(Reve/1000);
```

[more info on the official doc](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_math.htm#apex_System_Math_abs_2)